# Kubernetes trigger job on condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to trigger a job on some condition:
if:

```
kubectl get jobs -n <namespace> --field-selector status.successful=1 | grep "export"
```

do another job: perform removal:

```
kubectl get jobs -n <namespace> | grep "removal"
```

Such pods managing is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt functionality in Kubernetes. You can use kubectl create command but still you need to write your own script for your requirements. Please check this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) for your reference.